# How make Python test script auto register for my site

Tags: python, python-requests, automated-tests

I've site and want to add users to it using .python script
So I'm  trying to make python script that able to  **auto register**
I want to use **request** it's fast  , **and beautiful soup**
But i don't  know how to do it or how to start  I'm  beginner at python  so if someone could help  or have such  script  to modify it

Comment: You could use module `random` in python, checkout https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html

Comment: Sorry, your query is not clear. please elaborate.

Comment: I'm  have some knowledge about random  but now ned help for make auto register  script and add random  to make random generate mail and pass

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/661140/roberto my u help me please

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple script to generate email and password.

```
import random
import string


length = 10

#define data
lower = string.ascii_lowercase
upper = string.ascii_uppercase
num = string.digits
symbols = string.punctuation

#combine the data
all = lower + upper + num + symbols

#use random
temp = random.sample(all,length)

#create the password
password = "".join(temp)


random_char = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for x in range(length))

print(random_char+"@gmail.com")
#print the password
print(password)
```